# setInterval without calling a function Discord rpc

Tags: javascript, discord, discord-rpc

I was trying to make a little boop command on my discord rpc
but it ended up that using setInterval to get an updated version of the rpc ended up adding boops++;
since it was calling the URL function

any ideas on how to make it not call the function but keep everything working and updated? Is there a
better alternative to setInterval?

```js
var rpc = require("discord-rpc")
var fetch = require("node-fetch")
const client = new rpc.Client({
  transport: 'ipc'
})
let boops = 0
function url() {
  boops++;
  return "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/32/04/c5/3204c53493fcb595a5a87427f2d6cf71.gif"
}
client.on('ready', () => {
  client.request('SET_ACTIVITY', {
    pid: process.pid,
    activity: {
      details: `zoe hash been booped`,
      state: `${boops} times`,
      assets: {
        large_image: "image",
        large_text: "Nya~!" // THIS WILL SHOW AS "Playing <Status>" from the outisde
      },
      buttons: [{
        label: "Boop zoe✨",
        url: url()
      }],
    }
  })

  // activity can only be set every 15 seconds
  setInterval(() => {
    client.request('SET_ACTIVITY', {
      pid: process.pid,
      activity: {
        details: `zoe hash been booped`,
        state: `${boops} times`,
        assets: {
          large_image: "image",
          large_text: "Nya~!" // THIS WILL SHOW AS "Playing <Status>" from the outisde
        },
        buttons: [{
          label: "Boop zoe✨",
          url: url()
        }],
      }
    })
  }, 15e3);
});


client.login({
  clientId: "828106833251663912"
}).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: If you want to check in a certain interval then `setInterval()` is your tool of choice here.

Comment: What's wrong with the function call?

Comment: @arminyahya I want it to only use the function when someone clicks the button and am using setInterval to update the status showing the new amount of boops

Comment: @Lynx242 would update() work here somehow?